# websocket php client doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, websocket

I want to use websockets in an existing chat and I have the following code (from examples from socketo.me):

Pusher

```
class Pusher implements WampServerInterface
{
    protected $subscribedTopics = [];

    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic)
    {
        var_dump('on subscribe');die;
    }

    public function onPushEventData($event)
    {
        var_dump('push event');die;
    }
}
```

WebSocket server

```
public function actionStartSocket()
{
    $loop   = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $pusher = new Pusher();

    $context = new \React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);

    $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

    $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onPushEventData'));

    $webSock = new \React\Socket\Server('127.0.0.1:8081', $loop);
    $webServer = new IoServer(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
}
```

And I have a method for storing message to database.
Data comes in a `POST` request from Ajax and if it successfully saves, sends message to the websocket and returns the saved object to the client.

```
$message = $this->saveMessage($dialog, $currentUser, (string)$message);

$context = new \ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$socket->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

$socket->send(json_encode([
    "status" => true
]));

return $message;
```

I can't send data from the server to the websocket.
I use Apache as web-server and think that the virtualHost config is incorrect.

`Windows 10`

`Apache 2.4.33`, and modules:
`proxy`
`proxy_http`
`proxy_wstunnel`

`PHP 7.2.4`

Ratchet ([http://socketo.me](http://socketo.me/docs/push))
Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName proj
    DocumentRoot "c:/proj"
    <Directory "c:/proj/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks
        +MultiViews AllowOverride All Require local
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
    RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:5555/$1 [P]

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:5555
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you think the config is incorrect, then please show it to us.
Is it actually a database problem, or your code not being reached? Have you tried to debug it, to find out where the failure occurs?

Comment: Here is the config

`<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName proj
 DocumentRoot "c:/proj"
 <Directory  "c:/proj/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
 </Directory>

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
 RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:5555/$1 [P]

 ProxyRequests off
 ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:5555
</VirtualHost>`

The data is successfully saved to the database and return saved object to client-side, but the WS-server does not reach anything

Comment: Please include the config in the question, not just a comment.

Comment: > Have you tried to debug it, to find out where the failure occurs?
WS server successfully started and if i send him data from websocket-client in browser, he react.
But he does not react to PHP

Comment: Thanks for help, i upgrated question